# How can I address different types of VCS repos

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial

I have a small library and I want to make it possible to the users to add some
additional components to the library with the config file.

The user can create file `config` and to add there some stings that desribes
the urls to their VCS and the commit (or tag, or just branch).

Now I'm thinkg about this syntax, but maybe ther is some setteled type of
adressing?

I think to create such a syntax, but I hope to find out the common solution.

```
[library "jquery"]
vcs = git 
url = git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git
revision = 1.8.2

[library "cleonello"]
vcs = hg
url = https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot
revision = 81ec4eb933068c5009958b504feef3f27e1b1129

[library "webgeom"]
vcs = svn 
url = svn://svn.gna.org/svn/webgeom/trunk
revision = 52

[library "asdf"]
vcs = dir
url = file:///usr/share/asdf
```

Answer (score 0):

1. VCS is mandatory key for all SCM (the same protocol can be used in different SCM, you can't use it for differentiating SCMs)
2. For Git (case 3) id of changeset have to be also SHA1, not local number

**Note**: Git can't use svn:// protocol, is it `vcs = svn`?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you are right there was an error in the question (as you said, I've mistakenly written `vcs = git` insted of `vcs = svn`). I've fixed it in the question.